# Dynamics CRM 2011 Linq Cannot specify child attributes in columnset

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

```
var queryAccount = from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("cpar")
                           select new
                           {
                               cagid = !r.Contains("cagid") ? string.Empty : r["cagid"],
                               modifiedbyname = !r.Contains("modifiedbyname") ? string.Empty : r["modifiedbyname"],
                               ownerid = !r.Contains("ownerid") ? string.Empty : r["ownerid"],
                               solutionid = !r.Contains("solutionid") ? string.Empty : r["solutionid"],
                               createdon = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : r["createdon"],
                               subject = !r.Contains("subject") ? string.Empty : r["subject"],
                               baselineorr = !r.Contains("baseline") ? string.Empty : r["baseline"]



                           };
```

I am getting an error that says:
: +     base    {"**Cannot specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve. Attribute: modifiedbyname**"}    System.ServiceModel.FaultException {System.ServiceModel.FaultException}
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ModifiedByName is not an actual attribute on the entity.  You'll need to reference the value via the EntityReference:

```cs
var queryAccount = from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("cpar")
    select new
    {
        cagid = !r.Contains("cagid") ? string.Empty : r["cagid"],
        modifiedbyname = !r.Contains("modifiedby") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["modifiedby"]).Name,
        ownerid = !r.Contains("ownerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Name,
        solutionid = !r.Contains("solutionid") ? string.Empty : r["solutionid"],
        createdon = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : r["createdon"],
        subject = !r.Contains("subject") ? string.Empty : r["subject"],
        baselineorr = !r.Contains("baseline") ? string.Empty : r["baseline"]

    };
```